# LinkedIn url scheme opens EventMap application instead of Linkedin app

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, linkedin-api, url-scheme

In my application, there is the functionality of the open Linkedin application.
To open LinkedIn app I am using `linkedin://` URL scheme.

Now the issue is in my device I have **Eventmate** application installed & **LinkedIn** application installed.

Ideally, on `linkedin://` function call, it should open **LinkedIn** app. But its opening **Eventmate** application.

Comment: can you share the code you have written for managing app switch?

Comment: Added a code in question

Comment: linkedin://in/{username} will work

Comment: Please share the code you are trying